# Do we use RLMObject or Object in Swift Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I've seen examples for Realm where they use

```
class Person: Object {}
```

as well as

```
class Person: RLMObject {}
```

which one are we supposed to use?

Also, I can't get the init function to work for the former. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working in Swift, `Realm.Object` (`Object`) was designed for the Swift interface.  It has better type detection and more natural Swift phrases.

`Object` is backed by `RLMObject`, so you can use `RLMObject` if you want, but its an Objective-C api so some things may be a bit more tedious.

**tl;dr**

Realm made RealmSwift for a reason!  Use `Object` :)

Comment: Thank you.

Do you know the syntax for init? I can't get it to work with

    init(value: AnyObject){}

Comment: Are you also including just `override required init() {}` It's marked required in the Object declaration, so you'll need that as well. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/Object.swift

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.

    override init(value: AnyObject) {
        super.init()
        println("this is not called")
    }
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
        println("this is called")
    }

Comment: Define doesn't work.  It might be worth posting this as another question.